# Change value of input when user types in new value, else have default value

Tags: jquery, html

How do I change the value of a hidden input field to be what the user types in the  `<input>`?

**Input Fields**

```
 <input
     type="number"
     id="custom-donation-amount"
     placeholder="50.00" onfocus="(this.value == '50.00') && (this.value = '')"
       onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = '50.00')"


 />
```

and the hidden one:

```
<input id="paypal_value" type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!$('#custom-donation-amount').val()) { 
        ($("#paypal_value").val("50.00")) && ($("#custom-donation-amount").val("50.00"));
    }

    else $("#custom-donation-amount").change(function(){
  $("#paypal_value").val($("#custom-donation-amount").val())
});
```

Comment: Explain what `(this.value == '50.00') && (this.value = '')` is supposed to mean since `this.value = ''` will always be true (you are assigning a value with this, not comparing a value).

Comment: I think he is using short-circuiting as a shortcut for if-then - that is, I believe his code would be more easily read as `if (this.value == '50.00') {this.value = ''}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** the **[input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)** on the `number <input>` then just assign a variable to it's value then assign that variable to the `hidden <input>`.

Use the console to see the `hidden <input>` attain the `number <input>'s` value.
Added an `<output>` to conveniently test `hidden <input>'s` value.

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>input to input</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="inp1" min="50.00" placeholder="50.00" value="50.00" onfocus="(this.value == '50.00') && (this.value = '')" onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = '50.00')"/>
  <br/>
  <label for="inp2">Value of Hidden Input:</label>
  <output id="out1"></output>
  <input id="inp2" type="hidden" name="inp2" value="">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#inp1').on('input', function(e) {
        var input = $('#inp1').val();
        $('#inp2').val(input);

        // See the results in devtools or...
        console.log('inp2: ' + $("#inp2").val());

        // On the page itself.
        $('#out1').html($('#inp2').val());
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this works great. However, if the user submits it now, without there being a `value` on `#inp1`, the user submits a blank value on submission. May I add my original code back in there: `onfocus="(this.value == '50.00') && (this.value = '')"
       onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = '50.00')"`

Comment: I don't see why not, sure let's give it a try. That was on the input I believe.

Comment: I did add the value field back to the answer, that worked for me.

Comment: Just approved it, every improvement is a step forward.

Comment: I must have made a mistake. This is not passing through the value to PayPal unless the user inputs. It is not just accepting the value.

Comment: Are you using the submit event of `<form>` by post?

Comment: `$('#inp1')` = `$("#custom-donation-amount").` and `$('#inp2')` = `$("#paypal_value")` I changed the IDs to make them easier to remember for myself and easier for others to follow the flow. It should work when you change the IDs back for the real world.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to show the default value if user do not enter anything (or less than the default amount to the text box).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input_amt").on("focus", function(){
        $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).attr('placeholder')).toFixed(2));
        $("#paypal_value").val('');
    });
    $(".input_amt").on("blur", function(){
        $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
        if(parseFloat($(this).val()) >50)
        {
            $("#paypal_value").val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));   
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).val(parseFloat('50.00').toFixed(2));
            $("#paypal_value").val(parseFloat('50.00').toFixed(2));
        }
    });
});
```

*Add the class **input_amt** to the user input text box*

Comment: Hey @av_ajesh is `".input_amt"` the input value with the id `id="custom-donation-amount"`?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your last statement.

Comment: this is changing the value of the form input to "50.00" everytime. The user is no longer able to input their own value here.

Comment: @JonathanSafa: I make it to force the user to enter minimum donation 50.00 or higher

Comment: Oh that does make sense. Thank you for your help!